# Windows 7 asks administrator for administrator privilege

Tags: windows-7, malware

I seem to get a malware and when I try to delete it, it says I must be an administrator to delete it (I do not know the English version since I am not using an English version).

But the problem is that I am logged in as an administrator. What could be holding me back?

Comment: What antivirus are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 has 2 types of "admin" The Psudo admin, that is easily created and used, and the "Real" Admin , that is not normal for the system.  The purpose was to keep the system more secure so viruses would not run under full admin , and other reasons of safety and security of the system.  Which Admin were you?  Did you try logging in in safe mode?  The reason being, safe mode does not run as many items and drivers, in many cases (not all) the virus itself would be dormant. Another method would be to get into the disk without booting to that actual system that is infected.

Comment: @kinokijuf nothing

Comment: @Psycogeek I log in as the administrator(username). what kind of admin am I in the case?

Comment: You should seriously get an antivirus. Manually removing malware is not recommended. I recommend the free [MS Security Essential](http://windows.microsoft.com/mse)

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/507-built-administrator-account-enable-disable.html  I think I used this tutorial to get the real one.   also "Unlocker" could still be a usefull item for deleting things that dont want to go easily.  Disclaimer: both of the things can leave you worse off than you started if you dont know what your doing.  Using unlocker might be enough.

Comment: I would run something like Malwarebytes in Safe Mode before running Unlocker. There are too many unknown variables in the context of this malware infection. The disclaimer is noted :-).